# How to retrieve user password in cleartext using PAM?

Tags: c, pam

I am writing a PAM module which writes the username/password in a file for further transaction by an other application. I only saw the PAM_AUTHTOK item but I'm not sure from which type is it. Anybody knows that or another way to get the cleartext password?

Comment: Most (good) authentication systems don't store the cleartext password; they hash or otherwise one-way encrypt the incoming password and store that, and use it for future comparisons.

Comment: @Joe, that's true, but you're looking at this from the wrong side of the transaction.  PAM is the part that prompts you for your password and then validates; it doesn't "store" the password.  So PAM modules *do* have access to the cleartext password (this is what allows the `use_first_pass` option on many PAM modules to work).

Answer (score 11):

This is a very old thread, but there is also pam_exec:
https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec

e.g. Something like the following in the PAM Config:

```
auth sufficient pam_exec.so expose_authtok /usr/local/bin/myscript-example
```

Contents of myscript-example, echoing all the vars out:

```
#!/bin/sh
read password
echo "User: $PAM_USER"
echo "Ruser: $PAM_RUSER"
echo "Rhost: $PAM_RHOST"
echo "Service: $PAM_SERVICE"
echo "TTY: $PAM_TTY"
echo "Password : $password"
exit $?
```

Comment: Well, that may be so, but it will be a little difficult getting a shell script to compile as a C program, unless I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin pam_exec allows you to run a script and passes PAM related variables over to it (Hence the $PAM_USER, etc). This effectively allows you to write a PAM module in any language supported by the OS. Take a look at the linked Doc and you will see.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the Linux-PAM Application Developer's Guide?  On a RHEL-type system this will be in `/usr/share/doc/pam-devel-<version>/Linux-PAM_ADG.txt`, or you can find it online at [online at various places](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html).

Take a look at the *Getting PAM items* section, which documents the `pam_get_item()` function.  You can request the password with the `PAM_AUTH_TOK` constant:

> PAM_AUTHTOK
>
> ```
> The authentication token (often a password). This token should be ignored
> by all module functions besides pam_sm_authenticate(3) and pam_sm_chauthtok
> (3). In the former function it is used to pass the most recent
> authentication token from one stacked module to another. In the latter
> function the token is used for another purpose. It contains the currently
> active authentication token.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about just printing the contents of PAM_AUTHTOK when you're debugging? To make a meaningful use of it you must have some sort of a contract or convention between modules anyway.

By the way: there is a difference between keeping a cleartext password in memory and erasing it from there as soon as possible (or better: locking that region in RAM, or having encrypted swap), and writing that cleartext password to disk. The latter is just sooo insecure, don't do that.